# JQgrid set row height

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, height, row

I am using JqGrid with javascript.
I would set the height of each table row  but I have not understand how to do.

This is my code:

```
 function jobList(){
var json=doShowAll(); 
alert("jobList() ==> php/get_job_status.php?value="+json);
jQuery("#jobList").jqGrid({
    url:'php/get_job_status.php?value='+json,
 datatype: "xml",
    colNames:['id','title', 'start', 'stop','completed'],
    colModel:[
     {name:'id',index:'id', width:15,hidden:true, align:"center"},
     {name:'title',index:'title', width:150, align:"center"},
     {name:'start',index:'start', width:350, align:"center", sorttype:"date"},
     {name:'fine',index:'fine', width:350, align:"center", sorttype:"date"},
     {name:'completed',index:'completed', width:120, align:"center",formatter:highlight},//il solitoformatter:infractionInFormatter},  
    ],
    //rowNum:8,
    //rowList:[8,10,20,30],
    pager: '#pagerJobList',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
 multiselect: false,
 subGrid: false,
 autowidth: true,
 height: 250,
 rowheight: 300,

 caption: "Job Progress",
  afterInsertRow: function(rowid, aData){
     jQuery("#jobList").jqGrid('setCell', rowid, 'completed', '', {
      background: 'red',
     color: 'white'
     });
  },
  onSelectRow: function(id){
        //alert(id);
        var title="";
        if (id) { 
         var ret = jQuery("#jobList").jqGrid('getRowData',id);
         title=ret.id;
         //alert(title);
        } 
        else { 
         alert("Please select row");
        }
        var json2=doShowAll(); 
        subGrid(json2,title);
     } 

 }
);
```

}

Modifying RowHeight value rows height don't change. 
This is my table result

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: did u see this post : http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/possible-row-height-bug-in-in-ie8/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set height of individual rows of jqGrid or any other CSS property with the help of `setRowData` method (see [this wiki article](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods)). You can do this for example in `loadComplete`:

```
$("#list").jqGrid({
    // ...
    loadComplete: function() {
        var grid = $("#list"),
            ids = grid.getDataIDs();

        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            grid.setRowData(ids[i], false, { height : 20 + (i * 2) });
        }

        // grid.setGridHeight('auto');
    }
});
```

You can see a [working example here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/JqgridHeight.htm). Here you can see that after changing the height of the rows it could be a good idea to change the height of the grid. After un-commenting the line with the `setGridHeight`, the results will looks like [this](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/JqgridHeight1.htm).

**UPDATE** Based on the question from comment: To change the height of the header of the table with *id="list"* you can do the following:

```
$("table.ui-jqgrid-htable", $("#gview_list")).css ("height", 30);
```

The `$("#gview_list")` is a div over the grid body and the grid headers.

You can see results [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/JqgridHeight2.htm).

Comment: Thank you it works, but if I would change the height of head table?

How can I do it?
With this example only the row data height is modified.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 8):

This also works:

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th {
    height: 2em !important;
}
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td{
    height: 1em !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `ui.jqgrid.css` file change the line in the /* body */ section to this:

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    font-weight: normal; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    height: 22px; 
    padding: 0 2px 0 2px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px; 
    border-bottom-color: inherit; 
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

`white-space:` is changed from `pre` to `nowrap`.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue setting this rule in a css stylesheet:

```
.grid .ui-jqgrid-htable th,
.grid .ui-jqgrid-btable .jqgrow td {
    height: 3em !important;
}
```