# jqgrid Row Size

Tags: jqgrid

How do you force a row to be a given height?  I have a grid that has a column that sometimes has lengthy data and the rows auto-size to fit it in.  I'd like to force the rows to remain a uniform height, however all of my searches seem yield results from people trying to achieve the exact opposite.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is just set the CSS attribute 'height' of the row (of the `<tr>`) element. It is important that you can do this only after the row will be created. So you have to place the changing of the 'height' inside of `loadComplete` of `gridComplete` event handle.

[The answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203402/jquery-jqgrid-set-row-height/3204842#3204842) contain working demos. The usage of `setRowData` inside of the loop is not the best way from the performance side, but nevertheless the demos shows the main idea how to set the fixed row height dynamically.