# How to make free jqrid font awesome action buttons bigger

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid, jqgrid-inlinenav, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid 4.8 with font awesome icon set is used.

Standard action buttons are defined using colmodel

```
[{"name":"_actions","search":false,"width":(37+15)+45
,"sortable":false,"formatter":"actions","viewable":false,"formatoptions":{"editbutton":true,"keys":true
,"delbutton":true}]
```

additional buttons are added using code from

[how add button before action buttons in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10160660/how-add-button-before-action-buttons-in-jqgrid)

but they appear as jquery ui buttons even if font awesome classes are used in this code.

jqgrid row height is increased using code from [JQgrid set row height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203402/jqgrid-set-row-height)

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td {
    height: 2.8em !important;
}
```

but inline formatter action buttons are too small for tablets.

Toolbar button sizes are increased using

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-toppager .ui-pg-div > span {
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

from [How to make jqgrid top toolbar custom buttons bigger like standard buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530450/how-to-make-jqgrid-top-toolbar-custom-buttons-bigger-like-standard-buttons)
but this does not affect to inline action buttons.

I tried to use

```
.ui-icon {
    zoom: 1.5;
}
```

but this changes only jquery ui action buttons.

How to increase sizes of inline action buttons if font awesome is used ?
How to use font awesome icons buttons for custom jquery ui action buttons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem in many ways. For example you can add CSS rule like the following

```css
.jqgrow .ui-jqgrid-actions > .ui-pg-div > span { font-size: 24px; }
```

or

```css
.jqgrow .ui-pg-div > span.fa { font-size: 24px; }
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/navButtons0-fa4_largeAction1.htm) demonstrates the results. It used additionally another `width` value as default

```js
{ name: "act", template: "actions", width: 72 }
```