# JQGRID - Make checkboxes fit row height

Tags: css, checkbox, jqgrid, size

In JQGRID, I increased the row size of my table by doing this in the CSS file:

```
.ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow td input { padding: 0px; height: 60px;}
```

Since I have `multiselect: true`, how can I make the checkboxes to auto-fit the row size on all the grid (including header)?

I tried this answer which is working for the header but not able to reproduce it for the rest of the grid:
[How to increase jqgrid header checkbox size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881476/how-to-increase-jqgrid-header-checkbox-size)

So far they are way to small...

Thanks

Comment: Which is the version of jqGrid used?

Comment: jQuery UI - v1.11.2 - 2014-10-16

Comment: I ask for jqGrid version, not for jQuery or jQuery UI.

Comment: Sorry jqgrid is 5.7.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to jcarrera's answer, I finally made it by doing this with css (working with all browsers so far) :

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
        -webkit-transform: scale(2, 2);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these styles to the checkboxes, you can do it after creating the grid this way:

```
$("td input[type='checkbox']").css("height","100%").css("width","100%");
```

Comment: In wich part of the code please ?

Comment: it's working on safari  iOs , Firefox and Edge but NOT on safari for mac ... I emptied the cache and the cookies but still not working. Any Idea ? It's strange because the checkboxes are huge on iOs and Edge but just a little bigger on firefox . Do you know how to make them the same on all browsers ?